# IE7 margin issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

and thanks for the help.

I am having a somewhat confusing issue with IE7 when using margins.

I have a contaner, and inside that container I have some floated boxes.

These boxes have margins applied, top, right, left, bottom, except the first box that has no margin on the left, and the last box that has no margin on the right.

Looks fine in all browsers except IE7, where the margin is not applying for the first element in each row (at least this is what I think is happening.

If I remove margin right in ie7 using the dev tools and then check it back on it displays correctly.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

I am stumped.

***EDIT***
It appears to being caused by position:relative on the container divs. Changing this back to static fixes the margin issue, but now means my divs are mis aligned in ie7. Does anyone know why position relative would screw up margins??

***NEW EDIT***
Example download can be found here:
www.jimplode.co.uk/content/stackoverflow.zip

Incorrect view
[image: Incorrect]

Correct Margins, after unchecking and rechecking just one of the margin styles.
[image: Correct]

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="lowerContent">
    <div class="mediumContentBox contentBoxMarginTop contentBoxMarginRight contentBoxMarginBottom">

                            <div class="expandableBox">
                                <div class="topLeft">
                                    <div class="topRight">
                                        <div class="top"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="middleLeft">
                                    <div class="middleRight">
                                        <div class="middle">
                                            <img src="/images/frame/transparent.gif" alt="spacer"width="0" height="215" class="fl" />
                                            <div class="textContainer">
                                                <h1>Car Insurance</h1>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Protected NCD for life</li>
                                                    <li>NCD Accelerator</li>
                                                    <li>European Cover Included</li>
                                                    <li>Multiple Drivers and Vehicles</li>
                                                    <li>Breakdown Cover Included</li>
                                                    <li>Legal Cover Included</li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="boxButtons">
                                                    <a class="smallButtonLeft" href="#"><span>GET A QUOTE</span></a><a class="smallButtonRight" href="#"><span>FIND OUT MORE</span></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="imageContainer">
                                                <img src="/images/misc/boxphoto_1.jpg" alt="box image 0" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="emptyClear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bottomLeft">
                                    <div class="bottomRight">
                                        <div class="bottom">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="smallContentBox contentBoxMarginTop contentBoxMarginLeft contentBoxMarginRight contentBoxMarginBottom">

                            <div class="expandableBox">
                                <div class="topLeft">
                                    <div class="topRight">
                                        <div class="top"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="middleLeft">
                                    <div class="middleRight">
                                        <div class="middle">
                                            <img src="/images/frame/transparent.gif" alt="spacer"width="0" height="215" class="fl" />
                                            <div class="textContainer">
                                                <h2>Home Insurance</h2>
                                                <div class="imageContainer">
                                                    <img src="/images/misc/boxphoto_2.jpg" alt="box image 2" />
                                                </div>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Working at home Equipment</li>
                                                    <li>Helmet and Leathers</li>
                                                    <li>Legal Cover</li>
                                                    <li>Caravan Cover</li>
                                                    <li>Personal Accident Cover</li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="boxButtons">
                                                    <a class="smallButtonLeft" href="#"><span>GET A QUOTE</span></a><a class="smallButtonRight" href="#"><span>FIND OUT MORE</span></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="emptyClear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bottomLeft">
                                    <div class="bottomRight">
                                        <div class="bottom">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="smallContentBox contentBoxMarginTop contentBoxMarginLeft contentBoxMarginBottom">

                            <div class="expandableBox">
                                <div class="topLeft">
                                    <div class="topRight">
                                        <div class="top"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="middleLeft">
                                    <div class="middleRight">
                                        <div class="middle">
                                            <img src="/images/frame/transparent.gif" alt="spacer"width="0" height="215" class="fl" />
                                            <div class="textContainer">
                                                <h2>Life Insurance</h2>
                                                <div class="imageContainer">
                                                    <img src="/images/misc/boxphoto_3.jpg" alt="box image 3" />
                                                </div>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Cover From &pound;5 a month</li>
                                                    <li>Your loved ones protected</li>
                                                    <li>Immediate cover available</li>
                                                    <li>We search, you save</li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="boxButtons">
                                                    <a class="smallButtonLeft" href="#"><span>GET A QUOTE</span></a><a class="smallButtonRight" href="#"><span>FIND OUT MORE</span></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="emptyClear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bottomLeft">
                                    <div class="bottomRight">
                                        <div class="bottom">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="emptyClear"></div>

                    <div class="smallContentBox contentBoxMarginTop contentBoxMarginRight">

                            <div class="expandableBox">
                                <div class="topLeft">
                                    <div class="topRight">
                                        <div class="top"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="middleLeft">
                                    <div class="middleRight">
                                        <div class="middle">
                                            <img src="/images/frame/transparent.gif" alt="spacer"width="0" height="140" class="fl" />
                                            <div class="imageContainerAlternate">
                                                <img src="/images/misc/boxphoto_4.jpg" alt="box image 4" />
                                            </div>   
                                            <div class="boxButtons">
                                                <a class="smallButtonLeft" href="#"><span>GET A QUOTE</span></a><a class="smallButtonRight" href="#"><span>FIND OUT MORE</span></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="emptyClear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bottomLeft">
                                    <div class="bottomRight">
                                        <div class="bottom">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="smallContentBox contentBoxMarginTop contentBoxMarginRight contentBoxMarginLeft">

                            <div class="expandableBox">
                                <div class="topLeft">
                                    <div class="topRight">
                                        <div class="top"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="middleLeft">
                                    <div class="middleRight">
                                        <div class="middle">
                                            <img src="/images/frame/transparent.gif" alt="spacer"width="0" height="140" class="fl" />
                                            <div class="imageContainerAlternate">
                                                <img src="/images/misc/boxphoto_5.jpg" alt="box image 5" />
                                            </div> 
                                            <div class="boxButtons">
                                                <a class="smallButtonLeft" href="#"><span>GET A QUOTE</span></a><a class="smallButtonRight" href="#"><span>FIND OUT MORE</span></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="emptyClear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bottomLeft">
                                    <div class="bottomRight">
                                        <div class="bottom">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="smallContentBox contentBoxMarginTop contentBoxMarginRight contentBoxMarginLeft">

                            <div class="expandableBox">
                                <div class="topLeft">
                                    <div class="topRight">
                                        <div class="top"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="middleLeft">
                                    <div class="middleRight">
                                        <div class="middle">
                                            <img src="/images/frame/transparent.gif" alt="spacer"width="0" height="140" class="fl" />
                                            <div class="imageContainerAlternate">
                                                <img src="/images/misc/boxphoto_6.jpg" alt="box image 6" />
                                            </div> 
                                            <div class="boxButtons">
                                                <a class="smallButtonLeft" href="#"><span>GET A QUOTE</span></a><a class="smallButtonRight" href="#"><span>FIND OUT MORE</span></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="emptyClear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bottomLeft">
                                    <div class="bottomRight">
                                        <div class="bottom">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="smallContentBox contentBoxMarginTop contentBoxMarginLeft">

                            <div class="expandableBox">
                                <div class="topLeft">
                                    <div class="topRight">
                                        <div class="top"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="middleLeft">
                                    <div class="middleRight">
                                        <div class="middle">
                                            <img src="/images/frame/transparent.gif" alt="spacer"width="0" height="140" class="fl" />
                                            <div class="imageContainerAlternate">
                                                <img src="/images/misc/boxphoto_7.jpg" alt="box image 7" />
                                            </div> 
                                            <div class="boxButtons">
                                                <a class="smallButtonLeft" href="#"><span>GET A QUOTE</span></a><a class="smallButtonRight" href="#"><span>FIND OUT MORE</span></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="emptyClear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bottomLeft">
                                    <div class="bottomRight">
                                        <div class="bottom">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="emptyClear"></div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
    .lowerContent
    {
        position:relative;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    .expandableBox
    {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }

    .expandableBox .top
    {
        background-image:url("/images/backgrounds/bkg_whitebox_t.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        height:10px;
    }

    .expandableBox .topLeft
    {
        height:10px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
        background-image:url("/images/backgrounds/bkg_whitebox_tl.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:left top;
    }

    .expandableBox .topRight
    {
        height:10px;
        padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
        background-image:url("/images/backgrounds/bkg_whitebox_tr.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:right top;
    }

    .expandableBox .middleLeft
    { 
        padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
        background-image:url("/images/backgrounds/bkg_whitebox_l.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-position:left top;
    }

    .expandableBox .middle
    { 
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
    }

    .expandableBox .middleRight
    {     
        padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
        background-image:url("/images/backgrounds/bkg_whitebox_r.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-position:right top;
    }

    .expandableBox .bottom
    {
        background-image:url("/images/backgrounds/bkg_whitebox_b.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-x;    
        background-position:bottom;
        height:10px;
        margin-bottom:7px;
    }

    .expandableBox .bottomLeft
    {
        height:10px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
        background-image:url("/images/backgrounds/bkg_whitebox_bl.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:left bottom;
    }

    .expandableBox .bottomRight
    {
        height:10px;
        padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
        background-image:url("/images/backgrounds/bkg_whitebox_br.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:right bottom;
    }




    .contentBoxMarginLeft
    {
        margin-left:10px;
    }

    .contentBoxMarginRight
    {
        margin-right:10px;
    }

    .contentBoxMarginTop
    {
        margin-top:10px;
    }

    .contentBoxMarginBottom
    {
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
.fullContentBox
{
    width:940px;
    float:left;
}

.largeContentBox
{
    width:700px;
    float:left;
}

.mediumContentBox
{
    width:460px;
    float:left;
}

.smallContentBox
{
    width:220px;
    float:left;
}


.mediumContentBox .textContainer
{
    float:left;
    width:210px;
}

.mediumContentBox .imageContainer
{
    float:right;
    width:210px;
}


.smallContentBox .textContainer
{
}

.smallContentBox .textContainer .imageContainer
{
    float:right;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.smallContentBox .imageContainerAlternate
{
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

a.smallButtonLeft,
a.smallButtonRight
{
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url('/images/backgrounds/bkg_sprites_buttons.png');
    height:30px;
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:0px 10px;
    line-height:23px;
    color: #0F4DBC;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
a.smallButtonLeft:hover
{
    background-position:left -44px;
}

a.smallButtonRight
{
    background-position:right -217px;
    color: #4D4F52;
}
a.smallButtonRight:hover
{
    background-position:right -262px;
}


.boxButtons
{
    float:left;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.smallContentBox .boxButtons
{
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: off-topic and unrelated to your question, but if you want rounded corners in IE in a CSS-friendly way, without having to mess around with corner graphics I recommend you check out [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com).

Comment: yeah, css3 is not an option, have to support IE6 as well!! :( plus CSS3 is still not fully supported and some bits are still in draft. I would rather wait for standards compliance, rather than have to use propreitary styles for mozilla or webkit

Comment: Rounded corners use the standard form in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Ouch, that's **a lot** of `div`.

Comment: It appears to being caused by position:relative on the container divs. Changing this back to static fixes the margin issue, but now means my divs are mis aligned in ie7. Does anyone know why position relative would screw up margins??

Comment: Anyway, it seems to me (via the screenshot) that the problem may come from the big image in the first _box_ that have a too high padding and makes that block going too _far_ on the right. Anyway, I didn't watch the code or I think I'm gonna be blind.

Comment: @Chouchenos: it is an expandable box, therefore requires many divs.
@Rob: as stated I have to support IE7 and IE6.

Comment: @Chouchenos: You are wrong, just looking at the image is not going to tell you anything, and that is not the problem. I appreciate you trying to help, but at least try and be helpful by seeing how it works, not just guessing.

Comment: @jimplode - Do you have a link? Sometimes easier to work things out with Firebug on the live example. cheers.

Comment: sadly not, I can knock up an example and attach it. bear with.

Comment: zip of example can be found here "www.jimplode.co.uk/content/stackoverflow.zip". Only goes wrong in IE7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be something to do with margins collapsing. I would tempted to only have the margin on the left, then margin-left:0 on the first one.

Alternatively, try our old friend "zoom:1" on the floated divs or the parent container. Often fixes a lot of the more obscure IE weirdness.

Comment: "zoom:1" triggers what's known as "hasLayout". hasLayout is a boolean property that DOM elements have in Interet Explorer. You can't set it directly but setting a number of other properties does cause trigger it and "zoom:1" is my preferred method. Considerably more eloquent explanation here: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html